# Editing filesystem mount options outside of fstab for LUKS partitions

Tags: mount, luks

I have several LUKS encrypted drives attached to my system which do not mount at boot. I want to edit some of the options normally found in /etc/fstab (mainly noatime), but these drives aren't in fstab. I normally mount them through nautilus.

Where do I edit the settings for these drives?

Comment: Have you considered adding the drives to /etc/fstab but with auto-mounting disabled? Nautilus should use the fstab settings then.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/fstab just provides some defaults. You can always specify the mount options you want. You can also change some options later.

```
mount -o noatime /dev/sda9 /dir
mount -o remount,atime /dir
```